# active admin conditionally show csv link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using rails 3.2 with active admin 6.0 and I have different roles for active admin users, admins and agents but I don't want agents to be able to export the data, csv.

how can I hide all download links based on whether the user is an agent or an admin?

Comment: Are you using some kind of role manager? For example: rolify, cancancan,...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this? [Customizing Download Links](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages.md#customizing-download-links)

With proc you can use can? method.

Comment: I tried index download_links: proc{ current_user.has_role? :admin } do and it still doesn't seem to work...

Comment: index :download_links => proc{ current_user.has_role? :admin }.call?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, in `active_admin.rb`

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  # authorized? is an ActiveAdmin method that delegates to CanCan's can? method
  admin.download_links = proc { authorized?(:view_download_links, collection.klass) }
end
```

Then you just need to define an ability in `ability.rb` (swap `MyModelClass` for the name your model):

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    ... 
    can [:view_download_links], MyModelClass
  end
end
```

Using activeadmin 1.4.2 and cancancan 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You need rails [**`link_to_if helper`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if). **It will show up your link only when your condition is true**

```
link_to_if(condition, name, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)

<%= link_to_if(@current_user.nil?, "Login", { controller: "sessions", action: "new" }) %>
# If the user isn't logged in...
# => <a href="/sessions/new/">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

I had to monkey patch ActiveAdmin as follows:

```
# config/initializers/activeadmin_cancan.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  module ViewHelpers
    module DownloadFormatLinksHelper

      def build_download_format_links(formats = self.class.formats)
        if current_admin_user.can_download_resources?       
          links = formats.collect do |format|
            link_to format.to_s.upcase, { :format => format}.merge(request.query_parameters.except(:commit, :format))
          end
          div :class => "download_links" do
            text_node [I18n.t('active_admin.download'), links].flatten.join("&nbsp;").html_safe
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end   
end
```

The above should work as long as your users' ability to download csv files does not depend on the resource (e.g. some users can download Foo and other uers can dowload Bar) or format.

Answer (score 0):

With the current activeadmin version (1.1.0) you can do the following:

```
# file: app/admin/user.rb
index download_links: proc { authorized?(:export_csv, User) ? [:csv] : false } do
  # ...
end
```

and in your ability file (CanCan for example):

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(admin)
    can :export_csv, User if admin.superadmin?
  end
end
```